# what can i use form.cleaned_data in my to query a database?

Tags: python, django

`form.cleaned_data['question']` contains the string "do you like soccer"

and question model has 'do you like soccer' in its question field too

```
x = QuestionModel.objects.get(question= form.cleaned_data['question'])
```

Why does this get the error "QuestionModel matching query does not exist."

so why does it fail?

Comment: Are you sure that these two strings are equivalent? May be there is some spaces?

Comment: yeah, i just triple checked, could it be a unicode thing maybe, let me try

Comment: Print `repr(form.cleaned_data['question'])` and `repr(question_model.question)` to make sure they are the same.

Comment: @Alasdair how in the ./manage.py shell?

Comment: If you want to print `repr(form.cleaned_data['question'])` you need to add it to the view. You'll see the output in the terminal where you are running `./manage.py runserver`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try by getting the value in variable and then pass to queryset.

```
que = form.cleaned_data['question']
x = QuestionModel.objects.get(question=que)
```

This is the better way.

Comment: Its good that the OP has solved their problem, but reassigning the value to a variable like this won't affect whether the code works or not.